# RoR: How to access a model object in another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a new model in my app - PaypalOrder. Now in one of the methods of this model I want to be able to access `current_order` object. Where Order is an existing model. How can I do this in ruby on rails?

I read about associations, but they seem a bit complicated.

**EDIT**: 
The problem with using associations is that not every Order will have a corresponding PaypalOrder. But whenever there is a PaypalOrder I want to access Order. How can I setup this association

Comment: what do you want to do? it looks like you have a design problem, it's not clear why you need to access current_order inside PaypalOrder, also, associations are there to save you a lot of time, if you think associations are complicated then you may be using them the wrong way, write some example of what you want to do

Comment: @arieljuod I want to get the value of `current_order` object in the method and pass them to a script which makes an API call

Comment: @arieljuod : the problem with using associations is that not every `Order` will have a corresponding `PaypalOrder`. But whenever there is a PaypalOrder I want to access `Order`

Comment: check my answer, it uses associations, it's pretty simple and it doesn't care about Order having or not having a PaypalOrder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about:

```
class PaypalOrder
  belongs_to :order
end
```

?

you need an "order_id" column in paypal_orders table

and that's it

you then create a PaypalOrder with

```
def some_action
  current_order = Order.find(some_id)
  paypal_order = PaypalOrder.new(order: current_order)
  #do what you want with paypal_order
end
```

if you don't have the order_id do

bundle exec rails g migration AddUserToPaypalOrder

and the change method

```
add_column :paypal_orders, :user, :references
```

or

```
add_column :paypal_orders, :user_id, :integer
```

Comment: I have an order_id column in paypal_orders. The migration file looks like `      t.integer :order_id
      t.string :ip_address
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :card_type
      t.date :card_expires_on`. But how do I set this column value to the `id` of orders table??

Comment: the association takes care of that when you save the PaypalOrder record, paypal_order = PaypalOrder.new(order: current_order) sets paypal_order.order_id = current_order.id, then when you save paypal_order, order_id is saved to the db

Comment: Ok, now I understand. But how would I be able to find order by id. I don't know what the id of the current order would be. Any way of finding this out?

Comment: The order itsef is not saved yet, so there would be no id corresponding to it.

Comment: just get current_order the same way as you did before (the order data comes from a form? just instantiate a new order then with the data), then assign order to paypal_order the same way and rails will handle everything when saving paypal_order, it will save order and save order_id inside paypal_order

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is to use concerns, it works like this:

Model:

```
# app/models/PayPayOrder.rb
class PayPalOrder < BaseModel
  # concerns

  include MyMultipleNeededMethods

  ...

  def now_i_use_the_concern_method
    concern_method
  end

  ...
end
```

Concern:

```
# app/models/concerns/MyMultipleNeededMethods.rb
module MyMultipleNeededMethods
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def concern_method
    puts "refactored like a boss"
  end

  ...
end
```

Never ever try to cross reference methods this way. Use the given rails framework, its awesom ;-)

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your answer. I have updated the question, how can I setup the required association. I have not setup the association while creating the `PaypalOrder` model. Will I have to create it again now??

Comment: Was not expecting that you want work with associations. You need to work with :belongs_to and :has_one relations in the models and save the transaction to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... current_order and curren_user and usually current_s are tight to the session. So they can be accessed only by the controller. Since the models are handling business-domain logic they shouldn't access these objects...